# SQL- Block bounce data in Marketing Cloud for the year

Tags: marketing-cloud, bounce-management

I am not very well versed with SQL however I would like to query the data extension to find out what was the block bounce rate for all the emails sent out throughout the year.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/367816/edit) your question to add what you have tried (it's OK if it fails) and how it is not working (e.g., *exact* error text). This site exists to *help*, not do the work. (From the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of Help Center: *"We’re not a place to exchange code or find implementation services."*) Please read more of the Help Center, and also take the [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to pull all block bounces from Marketing Cloud? Below an example of how to achieve an overview including the subscriber and email name:

```
SELECT
      s.SubscriberKey     AS SubscriberKey
    , sub.EmailAddress    AS EmailAddress
    , job.EmailName       AS EmailName
    , s.EventDate         AS SentDate
    , b.EventDate         AS BounceDate
    , b.BounceCategory    AS BounceCategory
    , b.BounceSubcategory AS BounceSubcategory
    , b.SMTPBounceReason  AS BounceReason
FROM _Sent AS s
    LEFT JOIN _Job AS job
        ON job.JobID = s.JobID
    LEFT JOIN _Bounce AS b
        ON s.JobID = b.JobID
        AND b.ListID = s.ListID
        AND b.BatchID = s.BatchID
        AND b.SubscriberID = s.SubscriberID
        AND b.IsUnique = 1
    LEFT JOIN _Subscribers AS sub
        ON sub.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
WHERE s.EventDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -365, GETDATE())
AND b.BounceCategory = 'Hard bounce'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a non-SQL solution, you could generate an Account Send Summary report which includes total send and response data for your account.

This report includes information on all bounce types but will generate a Block Bounce Rate per send. If you export to FTP or Email a copy to yourself, you'll be able to manipulate the data in Excel.

For more info on the Account Send Summary, visit https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_re_account_send_summary_report.htm&type=5